# WordPress Website is running in 2 diffrent versions, one With WWW Prefix, One Without WWW Prefix on AWS (EC2)

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lets-encrypt, bitnami

I have recently installed WordPress Certified by Bitnami Application on AWS EC2, I found out the website was loading in 2 diffrent version on with www. one without www.

I found this code after some research and it worked for me

/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Later I installed letsencrypt SSL on my site, after installing ssl i am facing the same trouble

In order to force load ssl i had to enter below code in same file

```
RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(localhost|127.0.0.1)
 RewriteRule ^/(.*) https/www.xyz.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Please Help

Comment: I think Webmaster SE is the best place to ask such question.

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here, could you please let us know more information about what you trying to achieve? If you want to force HTTPS and www, the code you mentioned above should work if you include it inside the default VirtualHost block for the port 80 (/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf file).